# temp() not working on PBS Torque cluster with snakemake

Tags: snakemake

When I define an output/input file with temp(), the file does not seemed to be removed when running on a PBS Torque cluster.

Is this a known problem? if so is there a workaround? or a maybe a way to write a rule to remove a file when it is no longer required by other rules?

Comment: If there isn't a problem with storage, but you just want to delete the temp output afterwards you can use `snakemake --delete-temp-output`. However I don't know why your temp output is not deleted :(.

Comment: Can you show a simplified example code? Are you certain there are no other rules depending on those files?